# Let $X := \{{1, 2, 3}\}$ and $τ := \{{∅, \{1\}, \{1, 2\}, \{1, 3\}, X}\}$ be a topology space. Is it metrizable?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X := \{{1, 2, 3}\}$ and $τ := \{{∅, \{{1}\}, \{{1, 2}\}, \{{1, 3}\}, X}\}$ be a topology space.  Is it metrizable?

I am learning about topological space.

I read about metrizable topology space in Wikipedia and this post [There is no difference between a metrizable space and a metric space (proof included).](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215986/there-is-no-difference-between-a-metrizable-space-and-a-metric-space-proof-incl).

I have NO  idea how to approach this problem , any help is welcome.

Thanks !

Comment: Metrizable spaces are Hausdorff.

Comment: I didn't learn about Hausdorff ,so I have to solve the problem another way.

Comment: Then all you need is the triangle inequality.

Comment: You don't even need the triangle inequality. Let $a$ be the distance between points $1$ and $2$. By definition of metric, $a>0$. The open ball of radius $a$ about $2$ is an open set. Figure out what this set can be, and obtain a contradiction to the given $\tau$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A topology $\tau$ on a finite set $X$ is metrizable if and only if $\tau$ is discrete. Your $X$ does not have the discrete topology.

1. The discrete topology on any set $X$ is metrizable. Simply take $d(x,x) = 0$ and $d(x,y)=1$ for $x \ne y$.
2. If $d$ is a metric on the finite set $X$, then the metric topology is discrete. To see this, let $r  = \min\{d(x,y ) \mid x,y \in Y, x \ne y \}$. Then $r > 0$ and for each  $x \in X$ we have  $U_r(x) = \{ y \in X \mid d(x,y) < r\} = \{x\}$.